# How to Migrate web maps from ArcGIS Flex to JavaScript API?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-flex-api

A client has several web maps that were made using ArcGIS Flex. But the client needs all the current web maps to be changed to ArcGIS JavaScript API.

What steps need to be taken to make this happen efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably isn't the answer you want, but the Only solution is to do it by Hand.

Not only are the API's very different, even the Languages and framework are very different.

ActionScript might be a ECMAScript, but to run it as JavaScript, you'll have call JavaScript specific functions, and remove all the FLEX specific code.

The UI's that you have built in MXML, will have to be completely re-written in HTML and whatever JavaScript Framework that you end up using.